# Extraction of different types of variables from a large list

Tags: r

Let us consider an element of a list (g) whose first five elements printed as:

```
g[[1]][1:5]= 
[1] {'count': 1, 'max': 492.0, 'sum': 492.0}               
[2] {'count': 2159, 'max': 189.0, 'sum': 145109.0}        
[3] {'count': 394, 'max': 2779.0, 'sum': 571383.0}      
[4] {'count': 150, 'max': 1367.0, 'sum': 180339.0}      
[5] {'count': 4, 'max': 1072055.0, 'sum': 2453038.0}
```

where:

```
typeof(g[[1]][1:5])
[1] "integer"
```

Here $g$ is obtained from a python program and now I want to use it as an input of my R program. Here 'count', 'max' and 'sum' are three variables with corresponding values. My question is how to extract and store the values of these three variables as three different vectors? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like this all ended up in R encoded as characters, which were subsequently interpreted as factors. You could do a lot of involved string parsing, but I would think it would be easier to have the Python code emit the numbers in a more friendly format.

Comment: @joran..Thanks for this practical suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jsonlite:

```
x <- c("{'count': 1, 'max': 492.0, 'sum': 492.0}",
"{'count': 2159, 'max': 189.0, 'sum': 145109.0}",
"{'count': 394, 'max': 2779.0, 'sum': 571383.0}",
"{'count': 150, 'max': 1367.0, 'sum': 180339.0}",
"{'count': 4, 'max': 1072055.0, 'sum': 2453038.0}")

library(jsonlite)

json <- c("[", toString(chartr("'", '"', x)), "]")
fromJSON(json)
```

giving this data frame:

```
  count     max     sum
1     1     492     492
2  2159     189  145109
3   394    2779  571383
4   150    1367  180339
5     4 1072055 2453038
```

### Variation

This could alternately be expressed as the following pipeline:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

x %>%
  chartr("'", '"', .) %>%
  c("[", ., "]") %>%
  fromJSON
```

Comment: Many thanks. It would be helpful if further we get the output vectors of values of 'count', 'max' and 'sum' without using loop.

Comment: OK. Have revised to produce a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with RJSONIO, outputing the 3 desired vectors (detach jsonlite to use RJSONIO because both have the same function name "fromJSON" but works differently):

```
detach("package:jsonlite", unload=TRUE)

x <- c("{'count': 1, 'max': 492.0, 'sum': 492.0}",
       "{'count': 2159, 'max': 189.0, 'sum': 145109.0}",
       "{'count': 394, 'max': 2779.0, 'sum': 571383.0}",
       "{'count': 150, 'max': 1367.0, 'sum': 180339.0}",
       "{'count': 4, 'max': 1072055.0, 'sum': 2453038.0}")

library(RJSONIO)

toVector <- function(xdata, varname) {
  return(unname(sapply(1:length(x), function(i){
    fromJSON(x[i])[varname]
    })))
}

mymax <- toVector(x, "max")
mycount <- toVector(x, "count")
mysum <- toVector(x, "sum")
```