# Read messy json in R

Tags: r, json

I have a csv file with the following structure:

**Input**

```
{"eid":"START","ver":"3.0","ets":1514764800238}}
{"eid":"INTERACT","ver":"3.0","ets":1514764820546}}
{"eid":"IMPRESSION","ver":"3.0","ets":895732}}
{"eid":"IMPRESSION","ver":"3.0","ets":245636}}
{"eid":"INTERACT","ver":"3.0","ets":535235423525}}
```

As you can see, its not a valid json, for the above to be valid json, the structure should be the following:

**Expected Output**

```
[{"eid":"START","ver":"3.0","ets":1514764800238},
{"eid":"INTERACT","ver":"3.0","ets":1514764820546},
{"eid":"IMPRESSION","ver":"3.0","ets":895732},
{"eid":"IMPRESSION","ver":"3.0","ets":245636},
{"eid":"INTERACT","ver":"3.0","ets":535235423525}]
```

**Problem:**

I would like to ideally read the file and fix it and save as a JSON, 
that is

1. Replace "}}" with "}," everywhere except the last line
2. Append "[" and "]" at the beginning and end of the file

I tried using fromJSON(rjson), read_delim, but I could not read it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use vscode find and replace

Comment: how do we solve the except last line issue? I can use sublime to do this, but the json is very large in size

Comment: Are you _sure_ the `}}` ends each line?

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes, however at this point I cant even figure out reading this csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual find/replace is a terrible, terrible, terrible suggestion for reproducible workflows.

One option — assuming there really is a `}}` at the end of each line and the file is in `/tmp/badlines`:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ndjson)

readLines("/tmp/badlines") %>%
  sub("\\}$", "", .) %>% 
  ndjson::flatten(cls = "tbl")
## # A tibble: 5 x 3
##   eid            ets ver  
##   <chr>        <dbl> <chr>
## 1 START      1.51e12 3.0  
## 2 INTERACT   1.51e12 3.0  
## 3 IMPRESSION 8.96e 5 3.0  
## 4 IMPRESSION 2.46e 5 3.0  
## 5 INTERACT   5.35e11 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this question is nearly a duplicate of [Extraction of different types of variables from a large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237099/extraction-of-different-types-of-variables-from-a-large-list/50237275#50237275)

Aside from reading it in and running `fromJSON` (jsonlite package) a single line of base code can convert it to valid JSON (in variable `json`).

- replace `"}}"` with `"}"` using `sub` on each input line,
- insert commas between lines using `toString` and
- surround that with `"["` and `"]"` using `c`

Code:

```
library(jsonlite)

L <- readLines("test.json")
json <- c("[", toString(sub("}}", "}", L)), "]")
fromJSON(json)
```

giving:

```
         eid ver          ets
1      START 3.0 1.514765e+12
2   INTERACT 3.0 1.514765e+12
3 IMPRESSION 3.0 8.957320e+05
4 IMPRESSION 3.0 2.456360e+05
5   INTERACT 3.0 5.352354e+11
```

### Variation

This could alternately be expressed as a pipeline giving the same output:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

"test.json" %>%
  sub("}}", "}", .) %>%
  toString %>%
  c("[", ., "]") %>%
  fromJSON
```

### Note

Test input is generated with the code below:

```
Lines <- c('{"eid":"START","ver":"3.0","ets":1514764800238}}',
'{"eid":"INTERACT","ver":"3.0","ets":1514764820546}}',
'{"eid":"IMPRESSION","ver":"3.0","ets":895732}}',
'{"eid":"IMPRESSION","ver":"3.0","ets":245636}}',
'{"eid":"INTERACT","ver":"3.0","ets":535235423525}}')

writeLines(Lines, "test.json")
```